# how implement searchview with recyclerview correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, filtering

I have implemented searchView with recyclerView it is not working and giving errors I did not understand where I am making mistakes. below my MainActivity where I have implemented searchview logic

I have implemented searchView with recyclerView it is not working and giving errors I did not understand where I am making mistakes. below my MainActivity where I have implemented searchview logic

```
 class MemberActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private var memberAdapter: MemberAdapter? = null
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_member)
    
    
            val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
            compositeDisposable.add(
                ServiceBuilder.buildService(SpectrumInterface::class.java)
                    .getMembers()
                    .toObservable()
                    .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
                    .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it.members) }
                    .toList()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(
                        { members -> onResponse(members) },
                        { t -> onFailure(t) })
            )
    
    
    
            memberAdapter = MemberAdapter()
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL))
    
    
            private fun onFailure(t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    
            private fun onResponse(members: List<Member>) {
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                (recyclerView.adapter as MemberAdapter).setMembers(members)
            }
    
    
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }
    
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                memberAdapter?.getFilter()?.filter(newText)
    
                return true
            }
    
    
            ascendingButton.setOnClickListener
            {
                memberAdapter?.sortAscending()
            }
    
            descendingButton.setOnClickListener {
                memberAdapter?.sortDescending()
            }
    
        }
    
    
    
    }
```

below my Adapter where I have implemented filter logic

```
class MemberAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberAdapter.MemberViewHolder>() {
    private val members = mutableListOf<Member>()

    fun setMembers(data: List<Member>) {
        members.clear()
        members.addAll(data)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MemberViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.member_list, parent, false)
        return MemberViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = members.size




    fun sortAscending() {
        members.sortBy { it.age }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun sortDescending() {
        members.sortByDescending { it.age }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence): FilterResults {
                val query = charSequence.toString()

                val filtered: MutableList<Member> = ArrayList()

                if (query.isEmpty()) {
                    filtered.clear()
                    filtered.addAll(members)
                } else {
                    filtered.addAll(members.filter {
                        it.id.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
                            .contains(query.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)) || it.age.toString()
                            .contains(query)
                    })
                }

                val results = FilterResults()
                results.count = filtered.size
                results.values = filtered
                return results
            }

            override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence, results: FilterResults) {
                members.clear()
                members.addAll(results.values as Collection<Member>)

                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MemberViewHolder, position: Int) {
        return holder.bind(members[position])
    }

    class MemberViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val memberAge: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memberAge)

        //   private val memberName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memberName)
        private val lastName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastName)
        private val firstName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstName)
        private val emailAddress: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress)
        private val phone: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone)

        fun bind(member: Member) {
            memberAge.text = member.age.toString()
            lastName.text = member.name?.last
            firstName.text = member.name?.first
            emailAddress.text = member.email
            phone.text = member.phone
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: add your Logcat in question

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is updating `members` and then using it again as your base for future filtering.

Instead:

Create another list `filteredMembers` in `MembersAdapter`, initialize it to be equal to members in `setMembers()`

Make `MembersAdapter` reflect the items in `filteredMembers`

1. `override fun getItemCount() = filteredMembers.size`
2. 

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MemberViewHolder, position: Int) {
        return holder.bind(filteredMembers[position])
    }
```

Make your filter update `filteredMembers` and not `members`